# jquery addclass keeps reseting inside setinterval

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have an HTML DIV which is updated by ajax function using setinterval. What I'm trying to do is addclass to the result of ajax. But when setinterval the addedclass is reset and displays the initial class. how to solve this issue.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="something"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var id;
setInterval(function(){
somepage();
  addactiveclass();
 }, 5000);

function somepage(){
$.ajax({
  url:"fetchcontents.php",
  method:"POST",
  success:function(data){
  $('#something').html(data);
  }
 })
}
function addactiveclass(){
$('#list-'+id).addClass("active");
}
// UPDATED
$(document).on('click', '.mycontents', function(){
id = $(this).data('id');
$('#list-'+id).addClass("active");
}

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:** fetchcontents.php

```
<?php
     $output .= '<div class="list-item mycontents" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" data-name="'.$row['username'].'" id="list-'.$row['id'].'">';
//.... some php function to generate some contents inside the above div.....
// Contents do not interfere with this question.
$output .= '</div>';

echo $output;
?>
```

What happens is the active clas is not added to the div `id="list-'.$row['id'].'"`. As you know setinterval keeps on executing ajax function after 5sec and the active class is reset and not displayed.

Could anyone please guide me to accomplish this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not passed any parameter in `$.ajax`. So how can we understand what the `ajaxsuccess` is? Update your question.

Comment: hi @KrupalPanchal, I have updated my question above. My problem is that setinterval keeps on reseting the class to the initial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your code in jsfiddle, but replaced the ajax with a string defining a new div as contents of #something, and it works.

However it did require me to put the js inside a $(document).ready block

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your js in here
})
```

Try that.  What this does is not define the js until all the HTML is rendered. My guess is that you were referencing #something before it existed.

EDIT:=============================================

You have changed your code considerably since my answer was written, but to backup my claim to have a solution to what I believe was your question, I have re-done my jsfiddle test: https://jsfiddle.net/uf5h0sgw/

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="something">AAAA</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var id;
  var cnum = 1;
  setInterval(function(){
    somepage();
    addactiveclass();
   }, 1000);

  function somepage(){
  $('#something').html('<div class="abc">BBBB</div>');
  /*$.ajax({
    url:"fetchcontents.php",
    method:"POST",
    success:function(data){
    $('#something').html(data);
    }
   })*/
  }
  function addactiveclass(){
    /*$('#list-'+id).addClass("active"); */
    $('#something div').addClass("active" + cnum++)
  }

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot reproduce your ajax response, so I have just added some code to insert a DIV into #something every time the interval expires (reduced to 1000ms for the test).

Then the function addactiveclass() changes the class of the Div that has been added. I change the class name on a counter each loop so you can see that the class is updated every time around.

You will obviously have to adapt my code to handle what ever content your AKAX adds, but the approach should achieve what I think you want.

Comment: it still keeps on reseting the class to the initial. I have updated the question above.

Comment: I presume my answer was downscored because I did not provide the code I claimed was the solution. Fair call, and remedied now.

Comment: BTW, if you need to remove a class in the HTML that arrives in the AJAX response, you can use .removeClass(classname) as part of the addactiveclass() function.

Comment: Thank for your time. My problem is the addactiveclass function inside the setinterval stay active only on the first ajax call (somepage();) and on subsequent setinterval ajaxcall the class becomes inactive. So I have to restructure my code by removing the addactiveclass from setinterval on document load and instead putting it into the button clicked function. $(document).on('click', '.mycontents', function(){
id = $(this).data('id');
setInterval(function(){ 
   addactiveclass(); 
  }, 10);
}. Although there is a flickering but I'm able to get my desired result.

Comment: You say "the addactiveclass function inside the setinterval stay active only on the first ajax call" but in my code the addactiveclass() function is clearly called every time the setinterval function is run - you can see the colour changing.

Comment: Yes. I dont know, it behaves strangely with my code. Anyhow I have restructured my code and for now working the way I need. Appreciate your response and support. But I have one slight problem that is the flickering (minor) due to setinterval. Every setinterval keeps adding the active class and thus make the div slightly flickered. Do you have any suggestion to avoid this?